# Why is my CSS/PHP stylesheet not applied to my site?

Tags: php, css

I am using following (simplified) code for my PHP stylesheet

```
<?php header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8"); ?>      
/* Our dynamic styles go here */
/* We will check BOTH sidebars are there so we can adjust width of our content */
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar('secondary') && is_active_sidebar('main') ) {

 ?>

 #blogs{
 float: right;
 width: 530px;
 }

<?php } ?>
```

Now when I view source of my webpage I am getting this (exactly as should be):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="http://www.mypage.com/wordpressdevelopment/wp-content/themes/Endless_Theme/functions/dynamic_css.php">
```

So when I **click** my link above (`Endless_Theme/functions/dynamic_css.php`)

I am getting this output (so now I know that my PHP/CSS script is working) :

```
/* Our dynamic styles go here */
/* We will check BOTH sidebars are there so we can adjust width of our content */
   #blogs{
   float: right;
   width: 530px;
   }
```

But the problem is that my CSS/PHP is **not being applied** to my webpage! 
Can someone tell me please what I am doing wrong here?

You can see my **[PAGE HERE](http://www.vasinternetposao.com/wordpressdevelopment/two-columns-featured-three/)** 
It should display one sidebar on right side and another on left side but it is not working (but strange thing is that same code IS WORKING on my LOCALL machine).

Comment: which browser(s) are you testing with? is it the same in all browsers?

Comment: You have invalid content in your style. Remove that block of commented messiness from the top of that file.

Comment: Looks like the problem was in my comments and "blank space" after my PHP closing tags... THX guy's!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your file isn't valid CSS.  Try cutting out the commented chunks of PHP - I suspect you'll find it works then!

Answer (score 0):

Browsers heavily cache css files.

Either send an expires header in the css or cache bust the css include... basically change the url every time it is requested so the browser will see it as a new asset.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="http://www.mypage.com/wordpressdevelopment/wp-content/themes/Endless_Theme/functions/dynamic_css.php?cb=<?= time(); ?>">
```